# IIS 7.5 Application Initialization 1 failed to install

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, failed-installation

I'm using Web Platform Installer to install "Application Initialization 1" but I get a general "Fatal error during installation" message.

In the log file I see:

```
MSI (s) (9C:24) [14:04:47:315]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfix,,)
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : End CA Setup 
MSI (s) (9C:24) [14:04:47:315]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfix,
              \Users\GEORGE~1.VOV\AppData\Local\Temp\\HotfixPipeLine{3E0FEF42-B34C-40FE-8387-2EE0F22CE1A6}.msu^)
MSI (s) (9C:A4) [14:04:47:325]: Invoking remote custom action. D
         LL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI5385.tmp, Entrypoint: ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : Begin CA Setup 
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : Launching process with command line C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe 
        /quiet /norestart "C:\Users\GEORGE~1.VOV\AppData\Local\Temp\\HotfixPipeLine{3E0FEF42-B34C-40FE-8387-2EE0F22CE1A6}.msu" 
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : Process returned with exit code -2145124329 
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : Error in function InstallWindowsHotfixQuietly, hr=0x80070643 


1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : < !!ERROR!! >
                         Error installing hotfix '
                         C:\Users\GEORGE~1.VOV\AppData\Local\Temp\\HotfixPipeLine{3E0FEF42-B34C-40FE-8387-2EE0F22CE1A6}.msu', hr=0x80070643 


1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : Error in function ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA, hr=0x80070643 
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : End CA Setup 
   CustomAction ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfix returned actual error code 1603 
     (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
```

It looks like it's trying to install a hotfix.
I've having this problem on **4** different machines with Windows 7 Enterprize x64

Any idea how to fix this?

**Update**

I got the actual msu file from my "Temp" folder and I can see the hotfix it's trying to install.
it's a file called Windows6.1-KB2684600-v2-x64.msu
Support Link= http://support.microsoft.com?kbid=2684600

When I try to install this hotfix manually I get "The update is not applicable to your computer "

**Update 2**
I also asked on [iis.net](https://forums.iis.net/t/1233184.aspx) but they weren't able to help much

Comment: Have you fix this problem? I have same problem here. Somehow after re-installing windows and made some windows updates, the application initialization installed successfully. In another day after have a complete update, it ended prematurely. I have spent many days just to try to figure out what is the problem by re-installing windows over and over again, to find out why the "hotfix" says "not applicable for your computer". Maybe not compatible with another windows update?

Comment: @BennyChen Unfortunately no. I ended up using other machines to do my job...I also asked on forums.iis.net but they didn't help much https://forums.iis.net/t/1233184.aspx

Comment: @BennyChen Added a bounty.If it draws attention someone might be able to help you

Comment: When your trying to install it manually, are you sure that its a 64 bit version msu.

Comment: @nik_boyz Yes,it is the 64 bit version.(I tried the 32 one also and I get the expected message that it is not the correct version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem with my new laptop at work. I contacted Microsoft Support and after trying some different things they finally found out what was causing the installation of Application Initialization 1.0 module to fail on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64 machine.

We found that hotfix **2684600** which needs to be installed for Application Initialization module, is supposed to update the iiscore.dll to version 7.5.7601.21943. 
However, our existing machine’s iiscore.dll is already at version 6.5.7601.23403, it would make sense that the hotfix is throwing the “not applicable for your computer” error during installation.

Digging further, we found that the version 23403 gets updated when KB **3125574** is installed through Windows Update.

We followed these steps to resolve the issue:

1. remove the KB 3125574
2. install Application Initialization module
3. then install the KB on top of it

*Example of my the WebPI log:*

```
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : Begin CA Setup 
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : CA 'IISExecuteCA' completed with return code hr=0x0 
MSI (s) (50:7C) [16:13:58:536]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfix,,)
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : End CA Setup 
MSI (s) (50:7C) [16:13:58:537]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfix,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA,CustomActionData=94^C:\Users\HOLMBE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\HotfixPipeLine{8AF6C421-008B-4C45-ACB4-232AC5559253}.msu^)
MSI (s) (50:A0) [16:13:58:543]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI1F6E.tmp, Entrypoint: ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : Begin CA Setup 
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : Launching process with command line C:\WINDOWS\system32\wusa.exe /quiet /norestart "C:\Users\HOLMBE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\HotfixPipeLine{8AF6C421-008B-4C45-ACB4-232AC5559253}.msu" 
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : Process returned with exit code -2145124329 
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : Error in function InstallWindowsHotfixQuietly, hr=0x80070643 
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : < !!ERROR!! > Error installing hotfix 'C:\Users\HOLMBE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\HotfixPipeLine{8AF6C421-008B-4C45-ACB4-232AC5559253}.msu', hr=0x80070643 
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : Error in function ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA, hr=0x80070643 
1: IISCA ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfixCA : End CA Setup 
CustomAction ExecuteInstallWindowsHotfix returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
```

Comment: I followed the steps you provided and it worked. @BennyChen should be able to use this too. Thank you

Comment: Your welcome! Happy to help. I spent a lot of hours cursing over this one.

Answer (score 1):

As Susanne writes the installer tries to run KB2684600. KB2684600 patches some dlls, for example iiscore.dll. And if these dlls are already at a higher version the KB installation will fail the install. 
When checking all files getting patched by KB2684600 I found that all of them are updated in 3125574, so if you have 3125574 installed you dont need KB2684600.

When looking at installer in Orca tool I noticed that there is a command-line switch that can be applied to avoid installing KB2684600. 
Run the installation like this:

```
appwarmup_XXX.msi SKIPINSTALLWINDOWSHOTFIX=1
```